# Tumbleweed Badge for long time indicates "Not Possible" or "No One Knows"?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, tumbleweed-badge

Hello All,

If some one was awarded tumbleweed badge for a question for long time, then, does it indicate that what was asked in the question is not possible or no one knows the solution?

If for a long time a question is not answered or doesn't have any comments what the owner must do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tumbleweed is a "for fun" badge; the implicit message is "we're sorry this question isn't working out for you; keep trying!"

See this for some great tips:

[Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

> 1. You can "bump" your thread by **providing status and progress updates resulting from your own continued efforts to answer the question yourself**. I usually do that unless I really hit a dead end with no further clues to follow. Some times I eventually bring about enough understanding to realise the answer, and thus post a resolution to my own problem.
> 2. If you have enough points, you can offer a **bounty**, promising to give some of your points to the person who correctly answers your question.

The key is persistence.

Nobody should want to find out the answer to your question more than you do -- so show us proof that you're actively working towards a solution! If you are serious and show evidence of your hard work others will be more willing to pitch in and help.

(and, in contrast, compare this with the "do all my work for me" types of lazy questions -- not saying your question is one of these, but only using it as an example of what does *not* work.)

Answer (score 3):

I had one question that got ignored, and recieved the tumbleweed badge. Then because of a bump to the front page, it got a couple answers.

If it does not get any feedback, in the meantime, add some more detail and things you have tried so far to answer your question. Those valuable edits will give the question a bump to the front and many will see it again. Because of the added information, the question will be easier for someone else to answer also.

Answer (score 1):

Well... either of the two... or maybe no one who knows the answer has viewed the question, or considered it worth-answering.